# PIG Unable to Read Local CSV Leading to Job Failure

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Relatively new to the pig/hadoop ecosystem and encountering a frustrating issue when trying to execute a simple DUMP. I am trying to call the below pig script (the file is local, not HFDS, so I am opening the pig shell using `pig -x local`).

```
REGISTER utils.py USING jython AS utils;
events = LOAD '../test/events.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (patientid:int, eventid:chararray, eventdesc:chararray, timestamp:chararray, value:float);
events = FOREACH events GENERATE patientid, eventid, ToDate(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS etimestamp, value;
DUMP events;
```

However, when doing this, I receive the following error messages (failed job summary below, full PIG stack trace at bottom):

```
Input(s): Failed to read data from "file:///bootcamp/test/events.csv"
Output(s): Failed to produce result in "file/tmp/temp/305054006/tmp-908064458"
```

Pig Stack Trace:

```
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias events. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias events. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:925)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:746)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:822)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:452)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:280)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1375)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1034)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:997)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:910)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:294)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:540)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:235)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:801)
...20 more
```

I have seen similar issues in regards to failed jobs, but sadly I haven't managed to hunt down a resolution as of yet.

EDIT: I should mention that when following the PIG tutorial at the below link, I was encountering the same issue.

http://www.sunlab.org/teaching/cse8803/fall2016/lab/hadoop-pig/

Comment: See answer, accidentally posted as comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found I was able to "DUMP" the file by doing the following:

```
tmp = events 100000; --any int larger than number of rows
dump tmp;
```

I had seen a similar issue on here, and was able to resolve by running as root.